# How to specify parse query to get parse objects only if they have been updated? [Android]

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

We are using parse server and mongodb. Users request `ParseObject`s and store them locally on their device with realm. Later on users have to check for updates from that objects. `ParseObject` offers the `updatedAt` attribute, so we would request for objects where the `updatedAt` has been changed. For a single object the query would look something like:

```
ParseObject object = new ParseObject();
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>(ParseObject.getQuery());
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", "9jK7lGt7U").whereGreaterThan("updatedAt", object.getUpdatedAt());
ParseObject queriedObject = query.findInBackground();
```

We have modified the model of the query for this post. `ParseObject` is the pseudo of our model.

As said before, the query has to be modified to work with many objects. The `objectId`s and `updatedAt`s are known. **How does the query must look like?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a query [fromLocalDatastore](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#fromLocalDatastore()),

```
ParseObject queriedObject = query.findInBackground();
query.fromLocalDatastore();
```

And after the query on each object, you can call on each object [fetchIfNeeded](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#fetchIfNeededInBackground(com.parse.GetCallback))

On each object that you recieve you can do that:

```
object.fetchIfNeededInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    // all fields of the object will now be available here.
  }
});
```

With your code you can write this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>(ParseObject.getQuery());
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", "9jK7lGt7U").whereGreaterThan("updatedAt", object.getUpdatedAt());
query.fromLocalDatastore();
ParseObject queriedObject = query.findInBackground();


for( int i=0; i < queriedObject.length-1; i++)
{
    queriedObject[i].fetchIfNeededInBackground();
}
```

I hope my answer solve your problem

Comment: Thank you very much for helping so fast. Your method crystallized the solution. To mention, we use Realm as local datastore instead of Parse. But this is no problem, we just have to adjust the local query. Fetching will do the trick. We just thought of doing this with just one query. Thank you

Comment: @unheal1337 Perfect ! I'm glad that solve your problem ! 